# C# Timer will not stop on trigger enter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, timer, triggers

I have a beautifully simple script that displays a timer on Unity 5 UI. At a finish line the racer enters a trigger and the timer should stop. It doesn't. I get no errors it just keeps running like Forrest Gump! I plan to post timer results to a leaderboard if I could stop the timer. Here is my timer script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour 
{

    public Text timerText;
    private float startTime;
    private bool finished = false;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        startTime = Time.time;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if(finished)
            return;


        float t = Time.time - startTime;

        string minutes = ((int) t / 60).ToString();
        string seconds = (t % 60).ToString("f2");

        timerText.text = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    }

    public void finish()

    {
        finished = true;
        timerText.color = Color.yellow;
    }

}
```

On a triggered cube I haved placed the following script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class WinBox : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private void onTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        GameObject.Find("Green").SendMessage("Finish");
    }
}
```

I've changed collision detection to continuous on the rigidbody to my it more sensitive with no luck. Made the cube thicker. Nope, it just keeps on ticking. The vehicle "Green" is in a indexed container/empty game object. It is a networked multiplayer game, so it should probably be rewritten to find the game object with the tag, player. Or somehow the first tagged game object to enter the trigger. I think the problem is 'Send Message' I've never worked with that.  The text color change also didn't work, but that needs to be changed to enable confetti particles when the timer stops.  Any assist would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to solve as per the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few problems in your code:

**1**.Your timer won't stop because the trigger callback function is **not** being called. The trigger callback function is not being called because `onTriggerEnter` is supposed to be `OnTriggerEnter` with the `O` capitalized.

When you fix this, make sure that the collider has `IsTrigger` property checked/enabled too.

**2**.Another problem is this line: `GameObject.Find("Green").SendMessage("Finish");`

You are calling a function called `Finish` but the actual name of your function is `finish` from the `Timer` class.

Finally, instead of doing `GameObject.Find("Green");` in the `OnTriggerEnter` function, why not cache it in the `Start` function then re-use it? `GameObject.Find` is very expensive and doing it many times will slow down your game.

```
public class WinBox : MonoBehaviour
{
    GameObject green;
    void Start()
    {
        green = GameObject.Find("Green");
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        green.SendMessage("finish");
    }
}
```